# TextEditingController doesn't clear the text after .clear()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

So im trying to clear the textform after sending a message and if the message is empty the send button should be disabled , what i'm having is the onPressed for the button is never null , it's never disabled , and the text is cleared but if i send again it sends the previous text before clearing if that makes sense
so if i send Hello , it shows as empty but the button still active , if i resend again without entering anything it sends the same cleared text , any idea what i could be doing wrong ?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class NewMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMessageState createState() => _NewMessageState();
}

class _NewMessageState extends State<NewMessage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  String _enteredMessage = '';

  void _sendMessage() async {
    setState(() {
      _controller.clear();
    });
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add({
      'text': _enteredMessage,
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      'userId': user.uid,
      'username': userData['username'],
    });
  }

  void sayHello() {
    print('hello');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message...'),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _enteredMessage = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            onPressed: _enteredMessage.trim().isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the controller.clear at the end of the _sendMessage() function, order matters. Also instead of 'text': _enteredMessage, use 'text': _controller.text    try that and let me know if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

The reason you are having the error is that you are storing in the input in the `enteredText` variable but are clearing the controller's text, both of which are different. Which is why your `enteredText` still holds and send the same string after clearing.

### Solution

You don't have to use a separate variable to hold your input text if you have given a controller. The controller already holds the value of the input. Make the following changes:

```
IconButton(
  ...,
  onPressed: (){
    _controller.text = _controller.text.trim();
    if(_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _sendMessage();
    }
  }
)
```

Use the text from _controller with `_controller.text`

```
void _sendMessage() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add({
      'text': _controller.text, //<-- Update here
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      'userId': user.uid,
      'username': userData['username'],
    });

    setState(() { //<-- Clear at the end
      _controller.clear();
    });
}
```

### Finally

You can now get rid of the `enteredText` variable and the `onChange` callback.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense , thank you so much

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.